# Variable is null when cast

Tags: ios, swift, casting, nsnull

I have a variable content from a NSArray : `let content = application["content"]!`

When I print content, I have a String :
`print(content)` -> `My content`

But when I want to cast my variable to String : `let content = application["content"]! as! String`

I can't print my variable because it's null :
`print(content)` -> `Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1a0507768) to 'NSString' (0x1a0511798).`

Why ?

**UPDATE :**

My array when value is not casted :

```
{
    "application_title" = "Marina Kaye";
    "application_type" = discussions;
    "application_type_name" = Discussions;
    content =     (
                {
            content = "Le nouvel album de Marina Kaye";
            link = "?message_id=118";
        },
                {
            content = "Son album est num\U00e9ro 1 des";
            link = "?message_id=131";
        },
                {
            content = "Le nouvel album s'appel";
            link = "?message_id=126";
        }
    );
    "content_title" = "Messages utiles";
    "content_type" = "useful_messages";
}
```

My array when value is casted :

```
{
    "application_title" = "Marina Kaye";
    "application_type" = discussions;
    "application_type_name" = Discussions;
    content = "<null>";
    "content_title" = "<null>";
    "content_type" = "usefull_messages";
}
```

I can't cast content to NSArray and content_title to String.

**MY CODE :**

```
    let applicationsArray = result["applications"]! as! NSArray

    for application in applicationsArray {

        let applicationTitle = application["application_title"]! as! String
        let applicationType = application["application_type"]! as! String
        let applicationTypeName = application["application_type_name"]! as! String
        let content = application["content"]! as! NSArray
        let contentTitle = application["content_title"]! as! String
        let contentType = application["content_type"]! as! String
        self.listApplications.append(Application(applicationTitle: applicationTitle, applicationType: applicationType, applicationTypeName: applicationTypeName, content: content, contentTitle: contentTitle, contentType: contentType))
    }
```

Comment: a) Are you sure that's an array and not a dictionary? b) Could you try rewriting your code to unwrap things safely? In doing so you might find the cause of the bug becomes clearer. Doing things like `application["content"]! as! String` make it hard to diagnose exactly where a problem might lie.

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: application["content"] is an Array, right? You cannot cast it to string...

Comment: why are you casting this? where are you trying to use this?

Comment: You obviously should you NSDictionary here, it's not the proper way to store such data in NSArray.

Comment: I try to cast application["content"] to NSArray and  
application["content_title"] to String for create an object by initialization Object(content: content, contentTitle: contentTitle)

Comment: Bear in mind that in XCode the error messages sometimes appear against the wrong line and the error may be on the line before.

Comment: I can't cast to NSDictionnary, I have this error 'Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1a0506f98) to 'NSDictionary''

Comment: Please provide your actual code along with the smallest input that reproduces the problem fully; we need enough that we can try it on our own devices to see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I have edit my post with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are coding in Swift, you do not need the legacy `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` types. Instead, these are now `Array` and `Dictionary`, but you do not even have to care about that.

To declare an array, you usually specify the type in square brackets, such as `[String]`. For a dictionary, you need this for both key and value, separated by a colon, e.g. `[String: AnyObject]`.

From your log output, you have a Dictionary of type `[String: AnyObject]` with 6  keys; all of them point to `String` objects, except the `"content"` one.

The `"content"` key apparently points to an **array of dictionaries**. This is written like this: `[[String: AnyObject]]`. Thus it is not surprising that casting this to `String` is not successful.

Here is how you can parse the `application` dictionary's "content":

```
if let content = application["content"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
   for item in content {
       let text = content["content"] as? String
       let link = content["link"] as? String
       // do something with this data
   }
}
```

I would recommend defining a `class` or `struct` to capture the application object. Your code will be much clearer and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks it works for content, but contentTitle is always null.

Comment: That might be, but it should be unrelated to the above discussion.